# Checking if a user account is locked on another domain controller

Tags: command-line, active-directory

I'm trying to see if a user account has been locked out, using the command line.

I thought that I could do this with the `net` command, but when I run the command

```
NET USER username /domain
```

it processes the request on my domain controller; whereas the user that I want to check is on a different domain.  I cannot find a command/option to use the right domain (controller).

How do I check a user account on different domain to see whether it has been locked out?

Comment: Check this, it might help :
[net user using PowerShell][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033322/use-powershell-to-look-up-net-user-on-other-domains

Comment: "Net user" only works with the domain the machine is attached to, there's no way to specify a different domain.   Perhaps edit your question to be about the actual problem at hand (figuring out if a user in another domain is locked out) instead of about your supposed solution (using Net User), avoiding the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/174452).

Comment: Also thanks @techie007, I wasn't aware of this topic before.

Comment: Accounts being locked should result in a fast sync of the directory, and the status is supposed to be propagated to all the DCs very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to another account on the domain you want to query against, run the command as *that* account. Here are some ways to do this:

1. Use remote desktop to get to a computer in the domain
2. Use the Windows `runas` command-line command in front of your `net user` command
3. Shift + right-click `Command Prompt` and select `Run as different user`

Comment: #2 does not work for me, even when running command line under a remote user, it will still use the local domain.

Answer (score 0):

If your not required to use command prompt https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15201 can run a report on all domain controllers and allow you to unlock each via GUI.